# How to Create a Mobile app linking to an online/offline database

Tags: iphone

I want to code apps for both Iphone and Androids, im unaware of what is out there besides what ive googled, but i havent found some great resourses. If someone can lets me know which language is it easier and reliable, also which tools, even a reference to a good book i can buy. Also how it is possible for it to connect to an online database through a mobile. So if anyone can provide a few reference on how to go about it would be create thank you.

Comment: to android programming begin from here: http://developer.android.com/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go take a look at [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/). Its a cross platform development tool that allows you to develop native apps with HTML/Javascript (run through a UIWebView on iPhone), Also take a look at [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) and [Rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/) .
Appcelerator allows you to code for android (java) and then it converts the code to iOS for iPhone.
For data, I recommend Appcelerator cloud service.

Comment: @foxrotZulu thanks for the reply appreciate it!